# Using DefaultMessageListenerContainer to connect to WebSphere MQ throws "Connection closed" repeatedly

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I need to connect from a web application running on a **WebSphere AS 6.1**  application server to a remote **WebSphere MQ on z/OS** queue. On WebSphere AS, I configured both QueueConnectionFactory and Queue (an object containing a part of the remote queue data), with most of the settings set to their default values - I just needed to set queue name, channel, host, port, and transport type which is CLIENT. I inject them in the following **Spring 3.2** configuration using JNDI lookup:

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="destination" jndi-name="MyMQQueue" expected-type="javax.jms.Queue" />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="targetConnectionFactory" jndi-name="MyMQQCF" expected-type="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory" />

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"
      p:connectionFactory-ref="targetConnectionFactory"
      p:defaultDestination-ref="destination" />

    <bean id="simpleMessageListener" class="my.own.SimpleMessageListener"/>

    <bean id="msgListenerContainer"
      class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="targetConnectionFactory" />
      <property name="destination" ref="destination" />
      <property name="messageListener" ref="simpleMessageListener" />
      <property name="taskExecutor" ref="managedThreadsTaskExecutor" />
      <property name="receiveTimeout" value="5000" />
      <property name="recoveryInterval" value="5000" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="managedThreadsTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor">
      <property name="workManagerName" value="wm/default" />
   </bean>
```

JmsTemplate sends and receives (synchronously) messages correctly.  DefaultMessageListenerContainer, an asynchronous message receiver, reads some (previously sent) messages off the MQ queue during WebSphere AS start, but chokes soon afterwards, and begins to throw repeatedly "connection closed" exception. On each such occasion it notifies me that

```
DefaultMessag W org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer handleListenerSetupFailure Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue://myqueue' - trying to recover. Cause: Connection closed
DefaultMessag I org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

but stops taking messages off the queue.

Digging a bit into Spring code, I found that setting on DefaultMessageListenerContainer

```
<property name="cacheLevel" value="0"/>
```

solves the problem, in the sense that the messages are now being read off the queue every time I send them. However, looking at the TCP traffic to WebSphere MQ I find that MQCLOSE/MQOPEN commands are sent to it repeatedly as in:

[Wireshark captured traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urSlT.png)

which probably means that the connection gets continuously closed and reopened.

Can anybody suggest what might be the cause for caching not working properly, and whether there is perhaps a relatively simple way to modify Spring code (extending DefaultMessageListenerContainer, for example), or perhaps set some property on MQ queue connection factory/queue, to get it working?

**EDIT:**

Searching further the internet, I have found the following link

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/jms/89532-defaultmessagelistenercontainer-cachingconnectionfactory-tomcat-and-websphere-mq

which seems to describe a similar problem occurring on Tomcat. The solution there is to set a certain exceptionListener on DefaultMessageListenerContainer. However, trying to do this on WebSphere throws the exception "javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Method setExceptionListener not permitted". The underlying cause seems to be that J2EE 1.4 spec forbids calling setExceptionListener on JMS connections.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-getmess/j-getmess-pdf.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It seems that setting

```
<property name="cacheLevel" value="0"/>
```

on DefaultMessageListenerContainer is actually the correct solution.

I mislead myself by interpreting MQCLOSE/MQOPEN I saw on Wireshark captured TCP traffic in this case, as the heavyweight connection opening.

First, the newly created Connection Factory on the administrative console WebSphere AS 6.1 has by default a JMS connection pool (max size 10). By debugging the base class of DefaultMessageListenerContainer, AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer, (specifically the method

```
protected boolean doReceiveAndExecute(
            Object invoker, Session session, MessageConsumer consumer, TransactionStatus status)
```

)

one sees that neither the call to create a connection, neither the call to create a session from connection generate TCP traffic, and TCP traffic is generated only by creating a consumer (considered to be a "lightweight operation" if I understand correctly), trying to receive a message from the queue, and closing the consumer.

So it seems that the connection is taken from the respective pool, and also the session is somehow "cached".

So instead of caching by Spring, the caching appears to be done here by the application server.